# Hyperplane Reflection

Tags: inner-products, projection, reflection

Given the reflection $R_H(−2, 2, 2, −3) = (−4, 0, −2, 1)$,  what is the reflection of $R_H(−1, −1, −1, 3)$, and how I can find it ?

I tried to use $R_H = (2P_H b -I)b$, but I have no idea how to keep going on this exercise

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Let

$$U=(−2, 2, 2, −3)^T  \ \ \text{and} \ \ V=(−4, 0, −2, 1)^T  \ \ \text{giving} \ \ W=U-V=(2, 2, 4, -4)^T$$

(recall: the $^T$ operators mean that $U,V,W$ are transposed of line vectors, therefore are **column** vectors).

Let us consider the hyperplane $P$ with **unit** normal vector

$$N=W/\|W\|=\frac{1}{\sqrt{40}}(2, 2, 4, -4)^T$$

Taking the formula of the [Householder reflection matrix](https://nhigham.com/2020/09/15/what-is-a-householder-matrix/) (similar to yours) with respect to hyperplane $P$:

$$H=I-2NN^T=\left[\begin{array}{rrrr}0.8&-0.2&-0.4& \ \ 0.4\\
-0.2&0.8&-0.4&0.4\\
-0.4&-0.4&0.2&0.8\\
0.4&0.4&0.8&0.2\\
\end{array}\right]$$

It remains to apply this matrix to vector

$$(-1, -1, -1, \ 3)^T$$

Comment: Thank you!! i never seen the Householder formula before.  It be will very usefull